# unable to get data from the tables when applied where condition

Tags: sql, adb

```
Unable to get the data from the table after applying where conditio0n. manually checked all the tables the data is present in it.

Need help in resolving this issue.

I tried changing the where condition but still unable to get the data.

I assume the issue is in below condition however I'm unable to identify it

Below is the code:

SELECT
    a.OpportunityCode AS KPMG_Opportunity__c,
    CompetitorCode AS Account__c,
    CASE
        WHEN
            b.StageDescription = 'Won' 
        THEN
            'True' 
        ELSE
            'False' 
    END
    AS KPMG_Won_Opportunity__c, c.ConvertedOutcomeReasonCode, b.CloseDate, b.etl_rec_eff_end_ts, d.IsArchived 
FROM
    bpg_crm_opportunity_refined.oppty_competitors AS a 
    LEFT JOIN
        bpg_crm_opportunity_refined.oppty_header AS b 
        ON a.opportunitycode = b.OpportunityCode 
    LEFT JOIN
        bpg_oppty_mgmt_trusted.outcomereason_conversion_lkp c 
        ON b.OpportunityStatusCode_Orig = c.StatusCode 
    LEFT JOIN
        bpg_crm_engagement_trusted.edw_dim_entity d 
        ON b.PrimaryAccountCode = d.EntityID 
WHERE
    d.IsArchived != 'false' 
    and c.ConvertedOutcomeReasonCode != 'Z004A' 
    and date_part('Year', b.etl_rec_eff_end_ts) = '9999'
```

## Unable to get the data from the table after applying where conditio0n. manually checked all the tables the data is present in it.

Need help in resolving this issue.

I tried changing the where condition but still unable to get the data.

I assume the issue is in below condition however I'm unable to identify it

Comment: FROM
    bpg_crm_opportunity_refined.oppty_competitors AS a 
    LEFT JOIN
        bpg_crm_opportunity_refined.oppty_header AS b 
        ON a.opportunitycode = b.OpportunityCode

Comment: seems the issue persist in above code

Comment: Sure. It must be there. Your WHERE-condition transforms LEFT JOIN to INNER

Comment: @Sergey: Now able to get the data but getting null values from KPMG_Opportunity__c
and Account__c columns

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
a.OpportunityCode AS KPMG_Opportunity__c,
CompetitorCode AS Account__c,
CASE
    WHEN
        b.StageDescription = 'Won' 
    THEN
        'True' 
    ELSE
        'False' 
END
AS KPMG_Won_Opportunity__c, 
 c.ConvertedOutcomeReasonCode, b.CloseDate, b.etl_rec_eff_end_ts, d.IsArchived 
FROM
bpg_crm_opportunity_refined.oppty_competitors AS a 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT OpportunityCode,OpportunityStatusCode_Orig,PrimaryAccountCode,
         StageDescription,CloseDate,etl_rec_eff_end_ts
   FROM  bpg_crm_opportunity_refined.oppty_header
   WHERE b.etl_rec_eff_end_ts BETWEEN '99990101'AND '99991231'
)AS b ON a.opportunitycode = b.OpportunityCode 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT ConvertedOutcomeReasonCode,StatusCode
  FROM 
    bpg_oppty_mgmt_trusted.outcomereason_conversion_lkp c 
    WHERE ConvertedOutcomeReasonCode != 'Z004A' 
)AS c    ON b.OpportunityStatusCode_Orig = c.StatusCode 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT EntityID,IsArchived
  FROM 
    bpg_crm_engagement_trusted.edw_dim_entity  
   WHERE IsArchived != 'false' 
) D   ON b.PrimaryAccountCode = d.EntityID
```

May be something like this

Comment: Sorry but getting error while running above script...
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`b.etl_rec_eff_end_ts`' given input columns: [spark_catalog.bpg_crm_opportunity_refined.oppty_header.AccessibilityCode